# Why is one Function call throwing a null pointer exception while the other not?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I have two function calls as shown below in the `@Test` in the test class, one simply clicks on a webElement and other one performs an action to activate the dropdown (By simply hovering over using `action.movetoelement`) and then clicking on one of the options in that drop down.

My Program uses a POM with Page elements and the functions to be performed on those webelements in a separate class.

```
Package testcases;
import pageObjects.VisitHomePage;


---some code--

@Test
  public void test1() {

    login.eCommerceDemoSite();.// this throws a null pointer exception

     login.clickEnrollyourself();// this works as expected
  }
-- some code
```

---

```
package pageObjects;

public class VisitHomePage extends Base {


    By demoSitesLocator = By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/header/nav/ul/li[8]/a/span[1]/span/span"); //Locate Demo Site button/text on the toolsqa website
    By eCommSiteLocator = By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/header/nav/ul/li[8]/ul/li[1]/a/span[2]"); //Locate E-Commerce website link in the demo sites drop down
    By enrollYourSelf =  By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/ul/li/div[6]/div/div/div/a");

    public VisitHomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        visit("some website");

    }

    public void clickEnrollyourself() {

        click(enrollYourSelf);

    }
    public void eCommerceDemoSite() {
              perform(demoSitesLocator);// this throws a null pointer exception
              click(eCommSiteLocator);
              }
```

---

```
    package pageObjects

public class Base{

private Actions action;
    private WebDriver driver;

    public Base(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver =driver;

        }
public void perform(By locator) {
        WebElement element = find(locator);
        action.moveToElement(element).perform();//this throws a null pointer exception
        }

    public void click(By locator) {

        find(locator).click();// this works a expected
    }
}
```

I have tried and failed to resolve this issue, Kindly advise

Answer (score 1):

In your `Base` class in the method `perform` you're trying to call `action.moveToElement(element)` but you haven't instantiate action by the moment (so the reference is pointing to `null`). That is why you get `NullPointerException`.

Before you call `action.moveTo..` you should instantiate your action like:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
```